# Get segfault backtrace of child process

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, backtrace

I have two programs: `A` and `B`. They are different programs, `B` is not a fork of `A`. `A` launches `B`. Question: can I get backtrace of segmentation fault of `B` from `A`? I cannot modify source code of `B` program.

Comment: definitely you can. An usual way to achieve this is to enable coredumps which contain post-mortal snapshots of a process. The question is whether this is affordable for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They are different programs,B is not a fork of A. A launches B

By "launch", I presume you mean that `A` does a `fork` and the child does `execvp` of `B`

> I cannot modify source code of `B` program.

This implies that you *have* the source of `B`, but can *not* modify it, but *could* recompile it with `-g`, `-O0` and other things like `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` to get debugging symbols and a better chance at a more accurate stack traceback.

However, another way to interpret this is that you merely have `B` as a binary executable and do *not* have source code for it.

I also infer that you *have* source for `A` [and can do whatever is necessary to make things work].

> Question: can I get backtrace of segmentation fault of B from A?

Yes. There are a few different ways.

`A` can use `ptrace` when invoking `B` just like `gdb` or `strace` would do. When `B` segfaults, `A` can get control and walk back the stack and print it out.

But, this begs the question: Is your primary aim to [just] debug `B`? It might be easier to have `A` do a `fork/exec` of `gdb B` instead of just `B`, so that `gdb` can do the "heavy lifting" as a stack traceback is a simple `gdb` command. The even simpler way is to allow `B` to dump core by enabling the limit in a shell command and examining the core file with `gdb` afterwards.

Another possible option. Look at the symbols in `B` using `readelf` and the list of shared libraries it needs via `ldd`. You can then decide if `B` has any "hook" points. That is, any symbols it wants to call from a shared library such as `open`.

You can create a special shared library with `open` in it, then "force" it on `B` by setting the environment variable `LD_PRELOAD`. Then, when `B` calls `open`, your shared library gets control. You can then install a signal handler for `SIGSEGV` and then using `dlsym` get the address of the "real" open and finish the `open` call.

Now, when `B` segfaults, the signal handler in your special shared library can walk back the stack via `__builtin_return_address` et. al. and communicate the results back to `A` (via a pipe or socket)

Yet another way is to hack up the `B` executable and add a hook that way that communicates with `A`

Comment: I have `B` as binary executable. `A` is a program which automatically testing other programs provided by programming olympiad participants. Thanks! I will try all of your suggested solutions.